# convert data to 1NF

Tags: python, sql, database, first-normal-form

I have a dataset like this

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("music.csv") 
df
```

|  | name | date | singer | language | phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes or No | 02.01.20 | Benjamin Smith | en | 1 |
| 2 | Parabens | 01.06.21 | Rafael Galvao;Simon Murphy | pt;en | 2 |
| 3 | Love | 12.11.20 | Michaela Condell | en | 1 |
| 4 | Paz | 11.07.19 | Ana Perez; Eduarda Pinto | es;pt | 3 |
| 5 | Stop | 12.01.21 | Michael Conway;Gabriel Lee | en;en | 1 |
| 6 | Shalom | 18.06.21 | Shimon Cohen | hebr | 1 |
| 7 | Habibi | 22.12.19 | Fuad Khoury | ar | 3 |
| 8 | viva | 01.08.21 | Veronica Barnes | en | 1 |
| 9 | Buznanna | 23.09.20 | Kurt Azzopardi | mt | 1 |
| 10 | Frieden | 21.05.21 | Gabriel Meier | dt | 1 |
| 11 | Uruguay | 11.04.21 | Julio Ramirez | es | 1 |
| 12 | Beautiful | 17.03.21 | Cameron Armstrong | en | 3 |
| 13 | Holiday | 19.06.20 | Bianca Watson | en | 3 |
| 14 | Kiwi | 21.10.20 | Lachlan McNamara | en | 1 |
| 15 | Amore | 01.12.20 | Vasco Grimaldi | it | 1 |
| 16 | La vie | 28.04.20 | Victor Dubois | fr | 3 |
| 17 | Yom | 21.02.20 | Ori Azerad; Naeem al-Hindi | hebr;ar | 2 |
| 18 | Elefthería | 15.06.19 | Nikolaos Gekas | gr | 1 |

This table is not in 1NF. I would like to convert in  the form of pd.DataFrame, that satiesfy 1NF.

How can I do that?

I did this, but seems not work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
df = pd.read_csv("music.csv") 
 
lens = list(map(len, df['singer','language].values))
 
res = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.repeat(
    df['name'], lens), 'singer': np.concatenate(df['singer'].values),'language': np.concatenate(df['language'].values)})
 
print(res)
```

It should satisfy only 1NF not 3NF and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split `language` and `singer` by values and use `pd.explode`:

```
df['language']=df['language'].str.split(';')
df['singer']=df['singer'].str.split(";")
df.explode(['language','singer'])
```

| Id | name | date | singer | language | phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes or No | 02.01.20 | Benjamin Smith | en | 1 |
| 2 | Parabens | 01.06.21 | Rafael Galvao | pt | 2 |
| 2 | Parabens | 01.06.21 | Simon Murphy | en | 2 |
| 3 | Love | 12.11.20 | Michaela Condell | en | 1 |
| 4 | Paz | 11.07.19 | Ana Perez | es | 3 |
| 4 | Paz | 11.07.19 | Eduarda Pinto | pt | 3 |
| 5 | Stop | 12.01.21 | Michael Conway | en | 1 |
| 5 | Stop | 12.01.21 | Gabriel Lee | en | 1 |
| 6 | Shalom | 18.06.21 | Shimon Cohen | hebr | 1 |
| 7 | Habibi | 22.12.19 | Fuad Khoury | ar | 3 |
| 8 | viva | 01.08.21 | Veronica Barnes | en | 1 |
| 9 | Buznanna | 23.09.20 | Kurt Azzopardi | mt | 1 |
| 10 | Frieden | 21.05.21 | Gabriel Meier | dt | 1 |
| 11 | Uruguay | 11.04.21 | Julio Ramirez | es | 1 |
| 12 | Beautiful | 17.03.21 | Cameron Armstrong | en | 3 |
| 13 | Holiday | 19.06.20 | Bianca Watson | en | 3 |
| 14 | Kiwi | 21.10.20 | Lachlan McNamara | en | 1 |
| 15 | Amore | 01.12.20 | Vasco Grimaldi | it | 1 |
| 16 | La vie | 28.04.20 | Victor Dubois | fr | 3 |
| 17 | Yom | 21.02.20 | Ori Azerad | hebr | 2 |
| 17 | Yom | 21.02.20 | Naeem al-Hindi | ar | 2 |
| 18 | Elefthería | 15.06.19 | Nikolaos Gekas | gr | 1 |