# get the number of involved singer in a phase

Tags: python

I have a dataset like this

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv("music.csv") 
df
```

|  | name | date | singer | language | phase |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes or No | 02.01.20 | Benjamin Smith | en | 1 |
| 2 | Parabens | 01.06.21 | Rafael Galvao;Simon Murphy | pt;en | 2 |
| 3 | Love | 12.11.20 | Michaela Condell | en | 1 |
| 4 | Paz | 11.07.19 | Ana Perez; Eduarda Pinto | es;pt | 3 |
| 5 | Stop | 12.01.21 | Michael Conway;Gabriel Lee | en;en | 1 |
| 6 | Shalom | 18.06.21 | Shimon Cohen | hebr | 1 |
| 7 | Habibi | 22.12.19 | Fuad Khoury | ar | 3 |
| 8 | viva | 01.08.21 | Veronica Barnes | en | 1 |
| 9 | Buznanna | 23.09.20 | Kurt Azzopardi | mt | 1 |
| 10 | Frieden | 21.05.21 | Gabriel Meier | dt | 1 |
| 11 | Uruguay | 11.04.21 | Julio Ramirez | es | 1 |
| 12 | Beautiful | 17.03.21 | Cameron Armstrong | en | 3 |
| 13 | Holiday | 19.06.20 | Bianca Watson | en | 3 |
| 14 | Kiwi | 21.10.20 | Lachlan McNamara | en | 1 |
| 15 | Amore | 01.12.20 | Vasco Grimaldi | it | 1 |
| 16 | La vie | 28.04.20 | Victor Dubois | fr | 3 |
| 17 | Yom | 21.02.20 | Ori Azerad; Naeem al-Hindi | hebr;ar | 2 |
| 18 | Elefthería | 15.06.19 | Nikolaos Gekas | gr | 1 |

I convert it to 1NF.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
df = pd.read_csv("music.csv") 
df['language']=df['language'].str.split(';')
df['singer']=df['singer'].str.split(";")
df.explode(['language','singer'])
d= pd.DataFrame(df)
d
```

And I create a dataframe. Now I would like to find out which phase has the most singers involved.

I used this

```
df= df.group.by('singer')
df['phase']. value_counts(). idxmax()
```

But I could not get a solution

The dataframe has 42 observations, so some singers occur again

Source: [convert data to 1NF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74179423/convert-data-to-1nf)

Comment: Can you give the expected output? How do you want to handle the duplicate singers?

Comment: If you need to count only unique singers, use my second option with `nunique` in place of `count`. Also you might want to split on `'\s*;\s*'` to handle spaces.

Comment: It looks like you copied this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74179423/). If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to split/explode, you can directly count the number of `;` per row and add 1:

```
df['singer'].str.count(';').add(1).groupby(df['phase']).sum()
```

If you want the classical split/explode:

```
(df.assign(singer=df['singer'].str.split(';'))
   .explode('singer')
   .groupby('phase')['singer'].count()
)
```

output:

```
phase
1    12
2     4
3     6
Name: singer, dtype: int64
```